# m4_version_compare does not see variable

Tags: autoconf

I want to test the version of some package (e.g PCRE) in a configure.in script, and define C++ variables in a Makefile accordingly. I thought that the autoconf function m4_version_compare would do the trick, but I can't get it to work. I am sure I am not using it correctly.
I have the following in configure.in:

```
AC_INIT([MyPackage], 0.4)
# Checks for common programs using default macros
AC_PROG_CC

PCREVERSION=`pcre-config --version`
AC_MSG_RESULT([Detected PCRE version ${PCREVERSION}])
PCRE_POST_8_0=m4_version_compare([PCREVERSION], [8.0])
AC_MSG_RESULT([PCRE version >= 8.0: ${PCRE_POST_8_0}])

AC_SUBST(PCRE_POST_8_0)
AC_OUTPUT(src/Makevars)
```

then autoconf + ./configure produces the following output:

```
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
Detected PCRE version 8.12
PCRE version >= 8.0: -1
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
```

What am I doing wrong? It seems that m4_version_compare sees the variable PCREVERSION as being 0. Should I define this variable in another way? How?
Thank you.

Renaud

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `m4_version_compare` to compare version numbers found at `configure`-time.

The `m4_version_compare` macro takes two strings that must be known at the time `autoconf` runs to build the `configure` script.  Here you are comparing the string `PCREVERSION` to the string `8.0`, and the former is reported to be lesser than the latter.

What you would like to use is in fact the value of the shell variable named `PCREVERSION`, i.e., `$PCREVERSION`, unfortunately this value is only known when `./configure` runs, so that won't work.

You should make your own comparison using the shell or some other means.  Personaly I would rely on `AC_PREPROC_IFELSE` to let the preprocessor do two tests at once: make sure the `pcre.h` file exists and that it is recent enough.  Something like this might work (untested):

```
AC_PREPROC_IFELSE(
[AC_LANG_PROGRAM([[#include "pcre.h"
#if PCRE_MAJOR < 8 
#error out of date
#endif]], [[]])],
[pcre8available=yes],
[pcre8available=no])
```

Comment: I was about to update my question. Thank you for your explanation, I eventually got it working using AS_VERSION_COMPARE. Will post my answer now.

Answer (score 2):

I got this working using AS_VERSION_COMPARE, which is run at runtime (unlike m4_version_compare, as pointed out by adl). So the code I eventually use for achieving this is:

```
AC_INIT([MyPackage], 0.4)
# Checks for common programs using default macros
AC_PROG_CC

PCREVERSION=`pcre-config --version`
CMPV="8.0"
AC_MSG_CHECKING([is PCRE version >= ${CMPV}])
AS_VERSION_COMPARE(${PCREVERSION}, ${CMPV}, [PCRE_POST_8_0=-1], [PCRE_POST_8_0=0],[PCRE_POST_8_0=1])    
AS_IF([test "${PCRE_POST_8_0}" != "-1"], AC_MSG_RESULT([yes]), AC_MSG_RESULT([no]))

AC_SUBST(PCRE_POST_8_0)
AC_OUTPUT(src/Makevars)
```

I think it is nice because it is generic and will work with any program that provides a command to retrieve its version.
But I will keep in mind adl's trick for the case where the version is not directly accessible from the shell. Thanks!